# C# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync -> Error reading string

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Hi I try to call an web api by server side with:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var rsp = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Request>(url, model).Result)
            {
                if (!rsp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // throw an appropriate exception
                }
                var result = rsp.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
            }
        }
```

but I get error

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

If I try to call same url from jQuery

```
$.post('http://localhost/api/Test')
```

the server return

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 25 Oct 2015 12:15:56 GMT
Content-Length: 104

{
  "Header": {
    "Token": "Response",
    "Timestamp": "2015-10-25T14:15:56.0092197+02:00"
  }
}
```

The "model" arrive on api controller but I can't get response from request.

Comment: Never use `.Result` with async HTTP calls. Use `await`.

Comment: @ToddMenier More precisely, never use it in an ASP.NET project that uses System.Web, or a WPF or Winforms client.  i.e. any environment that uses a synchronization context that controls access to a "main" thread.  There are some scenarios where it is safe to use.

Comment: @DarrelMiller True, I generalized a bit. :) It's not always outright dangerous, but I think we can agree it's rarely *advantageous* to block on an HTTP request when you don't have to. I suspect the majority of the time when you see code samples like this, the dev either hasn't learned the TAP pattern (it's not exactly intuitive that `Result` means block and `await` means don't block) or hasn't embraced it as a best practice. I like to point it out when I see it, but probably could have expanded on it a bit here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadAsAsync<T>` attempts to deserialize the response to type T. In this case, you're saying you want to deserialize JSON to a string, which doesn't really make sense. Either use a type matching the response (i.e. a custom data structure containing `Header`, `Token`, etc.) or use `ReadAsStringAsync()` if you really want to get a string.